# What is the best way to handle optional element in SwiftyJSON?

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I'm using SwiftyJSON (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). Suppose I have a JSON response of one of the two formats:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

Or

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "foo": "bar",
    "user": {"id": 2}
}
```

I want to update my Swift object's "user" attribute only when the "user" element in the JSON is present. Right now I'm doing this:

```
let userJson = json["user"]
if userJson.type != .Null && userJson.type != .Unknown {
    user = User.create(userJson)
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this? Say, using Swift's `if-let` syntax?

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a more elegant way than what you're doing, but additionally what I did was move my checks in the constructor. What I do for my implementation is each class that can deserialize to a data transfer object, I must provide an implementation for a constructor that takes a dictionary as a parameter. The dictionary is json that comes from the API. I obviously ensure in my proxy layer that it can indeed deserialize, isn't null, and can be represented as a dictionary.

Because I know the API call can either return a bad response of some sort (handled generically from my proxy layer) or exactly the contract I need for that call (converted into a DTO) I can make some assumptions about what is returned.

In your case where you have the possibility of something not coming back, unless this is a complex project you could probably get away with making those sorts of checks in your constructor like this:

```
 required init(dict dictionary: NSDictionary)
 {
    self.id = dictionary["id"] as Int
    self.foo = dictionary["foo"] as String
    self.user = ( (dictionary["user"] == nil) ? User() : User(dictionary["user"]))
 }
```

So now in here, I say if it's nil return a new user object but maybe you want to just keep it nil. Otherwise if it's not, pass the "user dictionary" (a child in your original JSON, in this case {"id":2}) into the user class constructor, and it will pretty much do the same thing but hydrate your user object.

I guess the user class could be:

```
 required init(dict dictionary: NSDictionary)
 {
    self.id = (dictionary["id"] as Int)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because SwiftyJSON lets you use objects as though they exist (assuming that the user id always exists if a user object is returned), you could also use the following as a check to simplify things a little:

```
if let userId = json["user"]["id"].string {
  user = User.create(json["user"])
} else {
  // Do something else, or just ignore it.
}
```

Comment: This is nice! With a bit of hack feeling, though :)